# Firebase, how to implement scheduler?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When some information is stored in the firestore, each document is storing some specific time in the future, and according to that time, the event should occur in the user's app.

The first way I could find was the Cloud Function pub sub scheduler. However, I could not use this because the time is fixed.

The second method was to use Cloud Function + Cloud Task. I have referenced this.

https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a

This perfectly performed the function I really wanted, but there was a fatal drawback in the Cloud Task, because I could only save the event within 30 days. In other words, future time exceeding 30 days did not apply to this.

I want this event to be saved over the long term. And I want it to be somewhat smooth for large traffic.
I`m using Flutter/Firebase, how to implement this requirements above?

thank you for reading happy new year

Comment: You might consider looking at dynamic cron jobs

Answer (score 0):

You could check in the function that gets activated on document creation if the task is due in more than 30 days, and if so, store it somewhere else (maybe another document). Then have another process that checks if the task is now within the 30 days range and then have it do the same as the newly created ones. This second process could be run every week or two weeks.

Comment: so basically you mean, if it is 60 days, save 30 days twice? right? I also thought of this trick, but it has so many more tasks than necessary (assuming if it is 12 months?). and cause of that, I am not sure if it will be suitable for large-scale user processing.

Comment: I was referring to storing the tasks due in more than 30 days separately until they are in the scope of the 30 days. For example, if a task is due in 4 months it will be stored in another collection created for this purpose and will be checked every certain amount of time, until it is in the 30 days range and then be sent as a task. This way only 1 task will be created, not 4.

Comment: Sorry I don`t understand. Why it is 1? Aren't 4 tasks created over 4 months? (total)

Comment: You can write a cloud functions that will check this date field in all the documents and if it is within 30 days create a Cloud Task for it. Run this function every ~30 days with a cron job.